# How many selections of four of six numbered balls involve selecting exactly one or two of the first three numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a box, there are $6$ balls, that can be distinguished (numbered from 1 to 6)! How many possibilities do we have, by taking $4$ balls (all at once) without considering the order to have exactly $1$ ball from the first three, or exactly $2$ balls from the first three?

The idea that should be behind is to use addition principle and multiplication principle. But I really don't have idea how to solve this exercise. I know that the result should be $12$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**  We directly calculate the number of selections in which exactly one ball is selected from the first three and the number of selections in which two balls are selected from the first three, then add the two mutually exclusive cases.

*Selections in which exactly one of the first three balls is selected:*  Since four balls are being selected, if exactly one of the first three balls are selected, all three of the last three balls must be selected.  Thus, there are $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3}$$ ways of selecting exactly one of the first three balls.

*Selections in which exactly two of the first three balls are selected:*  Since four balls are selected, if exactly two balls are selected from the first three, then the other two balls must be selected from the last three balls.  Hence, there are $$\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$ of selecting exactly two balls from the first three.

*Total:*  Since the two cases above are mutually exclusive, the number of ways of selecting exactly one or exactly two of the first three balls when four balls are selected is $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{3} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$

**Method 2:**  We subtract the complementary event from the total number of possible selections of four balls.

There are $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to select four of the six balls.  Observe that any such selection must include at least one and at most three of the first three balls.  Therefore, we can calculate the number of selections in which exactly one or exactly two of the first three balls are selected by subtracting the number of selections in which all three of the first three balls are selected among the four balls.  If all three of the first three balls are selected, then the fourth ball must be selected from one of the last three balls.  Hence, the number of selections in which all three balls of the first three balls are selected is $\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}$.  Hence, the number of selections in which exactly one or exactly two of the first three balls are selected is $$\binom{6}{4} - \binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}$$

Comment: Thanks for showing both methods :)

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, there are 3 possibilities to choose 1 ball from the first 3 balls, and 1 possibility to choose 3 balls from the other 3 balls.

For the second case, there are 3 possibilities to choose 2 balls from the first 3 balls, and 3 possibilities to choose 2 balls from the other 3 balls.

Thus, there are $3*1+3*3=12$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2}\binom{3}{n}\cdot\binom{6-3}{4-n}=12$$